# How can I get the secrets in node js application code for already initialized vault?

Tags: node.js, hashicorp-vault

I have app-id, user-id and nonce, but not vault-token. How can i get the vault-token so i can use the read API to access the secrets in node application dynamically. I have saved DB credentials, which i will be using to connect to while rendering the page. Bellow is my code :

```
var options = {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  user_id: 'abc',
  app_id: 'pqr',
  endpoint: 'https://abcpqr.com:8200', // default
};

var vault = require("node-vault")(options);
vault.health().then ( (result) => {
  var isServerInitialized = result.initialized;
  console.log("isServerInitialized :: " + isServerInitialized);

  if (isServerInitialized) {
    vault.read('/v1/secret/mydb/db/root').then((readResponse) => {
      console.log("readResponse ::" + readResponse.data.value);
    }
    ).catch((readError) => console.error("readError:",readError));
  }
});
```

Bellow is the error i am getting :

```
[0] > node index.js
[0]
[1]
[1] > webapps@0.1.0 start C:\Users\userid\app\webapps
[1] > react-scripts start
[1]
[0] options :: [object Object]
[0] listening to Port 4000
[0] isServerInitialized :: true
[0] readError: ApiResponseError: missing client token
[0]     at handleVaultResponse (C:\Users\userid\app\webapps\node_modules\node-vault\src\index.js:58:21)
[0]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done `vault.init()` the token is available in the response;

```
vault.init({ secret_shares: 1, secret_threshold: 1 })
.then((response) => {
  vault.token = response.root_token;
})
```

Comment: Hey @jokarls, my vault is already initialized, so if i use that API again, it is throwing me error as it is already initialized. Any other API you suggest to get the token please ?

Comment: i could proceed using request callbacks. Thank you for you inputs though.